# Remaining unjoind threads despite joining loop

Tags: multithreading, perl, join

I'm using multiple threads in my `Perl` script and join them at the end by this code snipped:

```
my @running = threads->list(threads::running);  
while ($#running > -1) {
   foreach (@thrs) {
      $_->join() if $_->is_joinable();
   }
   @running = threads->list(threads::running);
}
```

But in 50% I get the error message `Perl exited with active threads`. 
Can someone help me? Thx

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not doing `$_->join() for @thrs;`?

Comment: Why don't you do just `$_->join for @thrs;`?

Comment: I call external tools in the threads and thought I need to check if they are joinable first... but it seems to work

Comment: `join`: "This will wait for the corresponding thread to complete its execution."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stop looping when there are no more *running* threads, but you should only stop looping when there are no more threads *of any kind*. In other words, you don't check if there are joinable threads. Solution:

```
while (threads->list()) {
   $_->join() for threads->list(threads::joinable);
}
```

Of course, that uses 100% CPU. The simple way to avoid that is to use:

```
$_->join() for threads->list();
```